# crypto words using md5 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, cryptography, md5

Having problem to crypto possible combination of 2 letters word ranging from 'm' to 'v' using md5.

It works if I use CryptoJS.MD5("sd").toString()

I tried converting index to string but the md5 function does not work.

Thanks for your time.

https://jsfiddle.net/5abg7d8n/

```
var encrypt = function(chars, length){
var chars = chars.split("");
var index=[];

(function loop(base, i){
    for(var k=0; k< chars.length; k++) {
        if(i>1) loop(base+chars[k], i-1);
        else index.push(base+chars[k]);
    }
})("", length)

return index;
}

var possible = "mnopqrstuv";
var length = 2
var index = encrypt(possible, length);

hash =  CryptoJS.MD5(index).toString();

$("body").html(hash);
```

Comment: You pass it an array perhaps it wants a string; `CryptoJS.MD5(index.join("")).toString()` - (FYI as I'm sure your aware this is irreversible)

Comment: I would like to crypt the possible word combination from m to v (i.e. index could be mm, mn, mo,mp,mq,mr,ms..,mv,nm,nn,..nv..)